How to find Thévenin voltage with dependent voltage source

I am not an electrical engineer, so I lack fundamentals. I was trying to solve for the Thévenin voltage, that is Vout at the open terminals A and B, but what makes it significantly difficult for me is the presence of a dependent voltage-controlled voltage source 0.5Vx that is opposite in direction to a 10 V voltage source.
I am also unsure what Vx is here and how to find it. I assume Vx is a voltage drop between the point after the 10 Ω resistor and the ground as seen in the diagram.
I did try to calculate the Thévenin resistance by setting the voltage source to 0 and got 10 Ω, but I am unsure if it is right. Now my main difficulty is to calculate Vout.

Your R result is correct. For VOUT, you can calculate the loop equations, but it's a little complex.
It may be easier to calculate the short circuit current. Since it is a linear circuit, that value is VOUT/ROUT.
When you short the output (A==B), you can calculate VX by inspection = 10*50/60 = 8.333, and so the dependent delivers 4.167/12 = 0.347. The 10V delivers 10/(10+50) = 0.167 A.
So the total is 0.514 A, and with ROUT=10, you get VOUT = 5.14 V.
